# Can I consider that Xj is a test bernuli help solve the problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The distributor of advertising stands at the exit of the subway and offers everyone an advertising leaflet.
Each of the passers−by independently takes a leaflet with probability p or refuses with
probability 1-p. Let Xj be the number of the passerby who took the j-th leaflet. Find the mathematical
expectation, the variance and the generating function of the quantity Xj . I've been sitting with this task for a long time, but I can't solve it in any way. I want to know  if the sequence Xj can be considered as a sequence of bernoulli trials

Comment: Please let us know of any thoughts you had while you were "sitting with this task for a long time". Also, what is your level of probability knowledge? What standard probability distributions (if any) are you familiar with?  Also, what is the source of this problem, and why are you interested in it?

Comment: i want to know if the sequence Xj can be considered as a sequence of bernoulli trials

Comment: Are you interested in the number of people who were *offered* the $j^{\text{th}}$ leaflet? Because only one person can actually *take* the leaflet?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: Xj is the number of the passerby who took the j-th leaflet. p-probability that j person took the paper, 1-p- that he didn't, respectively. can i use bernoulli